# "The specified folder could not be found in the store" when getting room appointments

Tags: azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to use [MeetEasier application](https://github.com/danxfisher/MeetEasier) to show availability of all our bookable rooms. It works for some rooms in another office of our organisation. For my office it does not work. First I thought it was because all rooms were not yet moved off premises to Office365, but now when they all are in Office365 I still get the same error: "The specified folder could not be found in the store" (errorfoldernotfound). Since it works great for some rooms where my user has not been specifically granted access to (those in other offices) I believe that the problem has to do with the rights/configuration of the rooms and not my user. What are your thoughts? What can I ask our IT guys to try? (I don't have access or knowledge of AD etc)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is usually a permissions issue.  For O365 your access id should have impersonation access to all rooms, as opposed to delegation (all access) rights.  Your IT folks should be able to confirm this.  Not familiar with MeetEasier, but presumably they have an option to select impersonation?

Comment: If this is about access rights on my account, how come I can read the data on rooms for another office?

Comment: I can't really say.  IT can define all kinds of groupings for resources and assign full access and/or impersonation rights to those groups to any set of users they please.  You might have access to the other office because those rooms are in a scope you have rights to, while other rooms in your office you do not have rights.